# console.log return undefined

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
//Load the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';

$sql      = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 500";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge">' . $row['level'] . '</span>
    <img id="' . $i . '" onclick="image();" width="30px" height="30px" src="' . $row['picture'] . '"><strong>&nbsp;' . $row['first_name'] . '
  </strong></li>
    <script>
function image(this) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
}
  </script>
  ';
  $i ++;

    }
}
?>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

**Why is this not working ?**
**Problem: Console.log is returning undefined.**
**Why do I get the undefined message? Is there a good way to avoid it?**

Comment: The issue is because the scope of the function when called via a `on*` event attribute is the `window`, not the element itself, hence `this` is not what you expect it to be. See the duplicate I marked for a solution. Also note that using `on*` event attributes is incredibly outdated and should be avoided. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

Comment: Try surrounding the script within:
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    )};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below example. You can achieve it by jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img_123" width="30px" height="30px" src=""><strong>test </strong>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Welcome glad to help you :) @HossemHamami